# Problem while building gz-msgs9 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gazebo, build-from-source

I am trying to build Gazebo Garden from source using [this tutorial](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu_src).
Everything till `colcon graph` is working fine, but when I do `colcon build --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF --merge-install`, I get the following messages while building gz-msgs9:

```
Starting >>> gz-cmake3
Finished <<< gz-cmake3 [0.96s]                      
Starting >>> gz-utils2
Starting >>> gz-tools2
Finished <<< gz-utils2 [2.52s]                                          
Starting >>> gz-math7
Finished <<< gz-tools2 [2.66s]                                      
[Processing: gz-math7]                              
[Processing: gz-math7]                                       
[Processing: gz-math7]                                         
Finished <<< gz-math7 [1min 45s]                               
Starting >>> gz-common5
Starting >>> gz-msgs9                           
Starting >>> sdformat13
--- stderr: gz-msgs9                                                      
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:63: include/gz/msgs/actor.pb.h] Error 255
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:3582: include/gz/msgs/wrench.pb.h] Error 255
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:80: include/gz/msgs/actuators.pb.h] Error 255
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:131: include/gz/msgs/altimeter.pb.h] Error 255
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:165: include/gz/msgs/annotated_axis_aligned_2d_box.pb.h] Error 255
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:114: include/gz/msgs/air_speed_sensor.pb.h] Error 255
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:97: include/gz/msgs/air_pressure_sensor.pb.h] Error 255
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:199: include/gz/msgs/annotated_oriented_3d_box.pb.h] Error 255
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:182: include/gz/msgs/annotated_axis_aligned_2d_box_v.pb.h] Error 255
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:148: include/gz/msgs/altimeter_sensor.pb.h] Error 255
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:216: include/gz/msgs/annotated_oriented_3d_box_v.pb.h] Error 255
--ignmsgs_out: protoc-gen-ignmsgs: Plugin killed by signal 11.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/build.make:233: include/gz/msgs/any.pb.h] Error 255
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:405: src/CMakeFiles/gz-msgs9.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< gz-msgs9 [9.68s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< gz-common5 [49.0s]                        
Aborted  <<< sdformat13 [2min 7s]                                           

Summary: 4 packages finished [3min 57s]
  1 package failed: gz-msgs9
  2 packages aborted: gz-common5 sdformat13
  2 packages had stderr output: gz-common5 gz-msgs9
  9 packages not processed
```

Comment: Sometimes a clean build resolves these types of issues. Can you remove the `build` and `install` directories created by `colcon` and try rebuilding.

Comment: What's your system setup? Do you have a version of protobuf that's different from the default in Ubuntu?

Comment: @azeey I do recall removing the binary install of Gazebo before building from source, and then doing a binary install again when the source install failed. Currently I have a successful binary install for my projects and a source install that's refusing to build.

Comment: `pip show protobuf` gives version 3.19.6 and `protoc --version` shows 3.6.1